# How to amend certain values as they get returned

Tags: sql, oracle

Some of the values returned in the Account_Name column from my below query have '(INTERNAL)' at the end of the name. Is something I can do with the query that says 'if the account_name ends with (INTERNAL) then remove / replace with ''?

'''

```
SELECT
    account_name,
    trading_strategy_group,
    bloomberg_code,
    net_position,
    CONCAT(CONCAT(account_name, trading_strategy_group),bloomberg_code)  as uniqueID
    
FROM
    ref_data_tgt.account_position_history
```

'''

Comment: Oracle nowadays supports ANSI SQL concatenation, e.g. `'pt1' || 'pt2' || 'pt3'` .

Comment: CAn't you use the function REPLACE? Ex: SELECT 
    REPLACE(
        account_name, 
        '(INTERNAL)', 
        ''
    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace account_name in your query with:

```
 replace(account_name,'(INTERNAL)','?')
```

Comment: i see now i have some apparently duplicate rows returned now that I have removed (INTERNAL) from the account_name. I sometime now have 2 rows with identical account_name, trading_strategy_group & bloomberg_code but they will have unique net_position values. Is there a way to group these to only return one row per matching account_name, trading_strategy_group & bloomberg_code and sum the 2 net_position values?

Comment: You will need to open a new question for that.